# Identifying USB devices

Tags: usb, uart

I have several RS232 to TTL UART converters plugged into my Pi. The problem is that their device assignments change sporadically. Sometimes the first device gets /dev/ttyUSB0, and another time /dev/ttyUSB1 and so on. Is there a way to either hardcode these device assignments, or programmatically identify the device? I was thinking about parsing "lsusb -v" output, but maybe there's a simpler method?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about linux in general, probably better in a linux stackexchange?

Comment: Agreed, but chaining multiple UART converters is a common task on a Pi. It's a super simple way of connecting multiple MCU's to the Pi without the hassles of networking an UART bus.

Answer (score 2):

A *partial* solution is to use the links under `/dev/serial`:

```
$ lsusb
  …
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 067b:2303 Prolific Technology, Inc. PL2303 Serial Port
$ ls /dev/ttyUSB*
/dev/ttyUSB0
$ ls /dev/serial/by-id/
usb-067b_2303-if00-port0
$ ls /dev/serial/by-path
platform-bcm2708_usb-usb-0:1.3:1.0-port0
```

I say partial, because some drivers aren't very good at identifying themselves as separate devices. Prolific adaptors are particularly bad at this; two or more PL2303 devices may swap ID at times. FTDI ones are better.

Comment: I have FTDI adapters, so I might swap some of the PL2303's. Thanks for the pointers.